# Only logged in users can change billing and recurring amount

Tags: permissions, recurring-contributions, iats

We are using Civi 5.1 on Wordpress 4.9

Today we got our recurring payments to work again when we switched to IATS.
When someone makes a recurring contribution, they receive an email reciept that says

> You can update billing details for this recurring contribution by visiting this web page.
>   You can update recurring contribution amount or change the number of installments for this recurring contribution by visiting this web page.

However, unless they are logged in, clicking those links just takes them to homepage of our site.  These are donors, they are not creating log in credentials when they donate.

I would like them to be able to make changes without needing to login.  I read the older post on this subject and tried those suggestions, by using the below URL.

***oursite.org/oursite-donate/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/updatebilling&reset=1&coid=xxxx&{contact.ch‌​ecksum}***

I even tried the change & to ? as someone suggested

***oursite.org/oursite-donate/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&coid=xxxx&{contact.ch‌​ecksum}***

When entering that URL while logged off I get the below message.

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. 
>   You do not have permission to access this page.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you replace the xxxx and squiggly brackets part with the actual values? If you entered it exactly as above you'll get errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two bits are required for anonymous users to be able to access URLs like:

/civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&coid=4263&cs=b88004e51f6c99b0601aceab7e489315_1530392348_168

1. Permissions: make online Contributions
2. Administer -> CiviContribute -> IATS Payments Settings
   Check the box: Enable self-service to recurring contribution Contact Billing info:

[image]

PS - as you may have noticed this is no longer working in higher 5.x versions of CiviCRM. This regression can be fixed with this solution (PR) which was posted here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12668 - unfortunately it was closed. It's only one line of code you need to add to this file: CRM/Contribute/Form/UpdateBilling.php

[image]

```
$processorParams['recur_id'] = $this->_subscriptionDetails->recur_id;
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you i am very pleased it is was that simple.  It is working correctly now.  I am loving IATS.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your question earlier. If you have any other Q please tag them with iats.